# MySQL data truncated for varchar 255 and string

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have multiple SQL table where I put data from data frames. Dataframes and table are all the same
So, I have this column (for working and not working tables):

```
('Image link', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', None, '') #working
('Image link', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', None, '') #not working
```

```
#from working data frame
https://th-test-11.slatic.net/p/1759682bed199624d614224377d25a76.jpg
68
<class 'str'>

#from not working data frame
https://th-test-11.slatic.net/p/5df4f037629b81516f5d5d0b960047eb.png
68
<class 'str'>
```

so, all my table update except for one with is throwing

`1265: Data truncated for column 'Image link' at row 1`

Re-creating table doesn't help.
Probably something with the specific data in that DataFrame. What is the problem, how to identify?

What I don't see?

Comment: How to reproduce this? Where is your code?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to supply it as it is in the data, not in sql. The sql code is working - I have 36 tables all the same structure and all from the same source and 35 of them are fine

Comment: I changed column to 'text' and it worked. But WHY? It is driving me crazy? The data is the same by all the parameters I can possibly check, but in 35 cases in varchar 255 and in this single one it is text. Any ideas?

Comment: you see that both are strings, both are 68 in Len and one is not accepted. It is not accepted anywhere. No table accepts it! into varchar field

Comment: Need to look at the `INSERT` query. I'm also curious about the end product, it shows 'data truncated' message but does the data really got truncated when you check the field?

Comment: Just to make it short: ``` add_item = (f"""INSERT INTO `{table_name}`
                    (`Image link` )VALUES (%s)""").....data_item = (x['Image link']...... cursor.execute(add_item,data_item)```

Comment: no data remains normal string with the same length

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out.
It was primitive - one link deep in data was 260 long, I couldn't see it until I filtered by length.
So, my mistake is that I thought that "row 1" in the error does mean row 1.
And of course that is some unexpected issue that will be better dealt with 'text' field as if out of hundreds links all will be well below 100 in Len and one can be longer than 255 - that is what happens

thanks everyone